# what's best approach permalink database with zf2 and doctrine2?

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, permalinks

i'm building a web site with zf2 and doctrine. How can i save permalink to the my database? What's the best approach way? Should i save permalink in my entities?

```
//Product Doctirine Entity

public function setProdName($prodName){
     $this->prodName = $prodName;

     //is this right way?
     $this->setSeoLink = urlhelper->url($prodName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create  your urls using hash, like

```
/this-is-the-product-title-xyz123.html
```

where xyz123 is the hash of your product.

Doing this you'll have these advantage

1) you can change your product title anytime, your product can always be reached even the search engine or links in other website has the old one, for instance both

```
/this-is-my-product-xyz123.html
```

and

```
/this-is-my-wonderful-product-xyz123.html
```

will work.

2) you are not showing the real id to people.

To accomplish this I used the [HashId](http://www.hashids.org/) module, creating a factory service that return an already configurated object, then you can encrypt/descript using this code:

```
$hashids = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('my.service.hashid');
// decrypt having hash
$id = $hashids->decrypt($hash);
// encrypt having id
$hash = $hashids->encrypt($id);
```

The .html suffix is just as example, you can create your url as you wish.